# image and text in horizontal scroll View (dynamically)

Tags: android

I want to have in a horizontal Scroll View images and below each image i want a Text View. I want this dynamically. Until now i have Buttons with background for image, i use the method set Text for the text and it works. But, i want to edit the text separately from image, because i want a different color for text in order to be visible. This is my xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ImagesHsw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

update:

```
vi=      ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.actor,null);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.actorImage);
    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.actorName);
    for (int i=0; i<actors; i++) {
           b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.actor);
           b.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(160,150));
           text.setText(i);
           actorsScrollView.addView(vi);
}
```

Comment: can u try it with [HorizontalVariableListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView)

Comment: i have thought about the horizontal ListView and i had found this post http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34, but i had problems with imports.

Comment: Have u add the library properly ?

Comment: Probably not. Finally, i used the below answer... But thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have separate xml file with image and text as u expect.
Then add dynamically using inflate

```
for (int i = 0; i < actors; i++) {
    View vi = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.actor, null);
    Button b = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.actorImage);
    TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.actorName);

    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.actor);
    text.setText(i);

    actorsScrollView.addView(vi);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The program crashes in 'urLL.addView(vi)'. It shows this message:  The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: I can only add a comment.. And as a comment I don't think that you'll be able to understand because i can't change line.

Comment: I've just try your code and it doesn't crash but the layoutParams aren't the same for all. Also, the text doesn't appear for all the images.

Comment: I managed to fix the size from xml file and now all the images have the same size and also the text appears.